# window.location = "/"; Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Location | (string & Location)

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to reload my page after a function has completed, using the method:

```
window.location = "/"
```

but I keep getting the typescript error saying I can't assign a string to type location, which is weird because isn't a location always a string?

This is what I tried:

```
window.location.assign("/");
```

and it worked, but I don't understand why does the previous solution not work?

Comment: You could use window.location.href = window.location.href

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`window.location` is an `Object` which has the propertly `href` which is a `String`. You want `window.location.href = "/"`.